# What's the right way to say “match anything” with dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

What is the proper way to use `dplyr::filter` programmatically to match to any value, depending on the value of the filter critereon?

For example, I want to be able to write

```
my_filter(df, some_var == 1, another_var == 'any')
```

and have this return the same result as

```
filter(df, some_var == 1))
```

That is, the special value `'any'` means “don't filter on this variable at all”.

I was thinking of making a wrapper that takes the ellipsis `...` and removes any arguments that have the special value, but of course that doesn't work, because of the semantics of `dplyr`'s bare arguments and `tidyeval`'s quosures.

Comment: Can you please provide an example and expected output

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: IIUC, you're trying to do something that is unnatural for tidy eval APIs: you're giving semantics to syntax rather than values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of things that is much more natural to do at the level of functions rather than with meta-programming. For instance, you could create your own version of `==` that treats `"any"` as a special value:

```
my_equals <- function(x, y) {
  if (y == "any") {
    TRUE
  } else {
    x == y
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in `filter()`:

```
filter(mtcars, my_equals(cyl, "6"), my_equals(am, "1"))
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

filter(mtcars, my_equals(cyl, "6"), my_equals(am, "any"))
#>    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> 6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

If you really want to use `==` instead of a normal function, you could capture quosures and modify their environments so that `==` is masked by your function. Fortunately this is easy to do:

```
library("rlang")

quo_mask_equals <- function(quo) {
  # Create a child of the quosure environment which contains a binding
  # that masks `==` with our own function:
  env <- env(quo_get_env(quo), `==` = my_equals)
  quo_set_env(quo, env)
}

my_filter <- function(.data, ...) {
  quos <- lapply(enquos(...), quo_mask_equals)
  filter(.data, !!!quos)
}

my_filter(mtcars, cyl == "6", am == "1")
my_filter(mtcars, cyl == "6", am == "any")
#> *Same results as above*
```

However I don't recommend writing or using this kind of UI because it isn't compatible with the usual R semantics for `==`. I would at least use a special sentinel value rather than a value that could very well occur naturally in data:

```
ANY <- function() structure(list(), class = "my_any")

my_equals <- function(x, y) {
  if (inherits(x, "my_any") || inherits(y, "my_any")) {
    TRUE
  } else {
    x == y
  }
}

my_filter(mtcars, cyl == "6", am == ANY())
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. I had thought of using a sentinel, since that's definitely the right way to do it, but I didn't know how to implement one in R. Python's my main language, where it's as simple as `ANY = object()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this with `tidyeval`, though it's a hack in my view, since it requires comparing the bare arguments as strings:

```
# Like dplyr::filter, but with a special value that means “match anything”.
# If the RHS of any filter expression is 'all', that expression has no effect.
# For example:
#    my_filter(data, some_var == 'all')
# would return all rows.
my_filter = function(data, ...) {
  args = discard(quos(...), function(x) endsWith(quo_name(x), "\"all\""))
  data %>% filter(!!! args)
}
```